# Picture not being saved Android

Tags: java, android, file, android-imageview

At the click of a button, I want to start an Intent to take a picture, and then display it in my layout. I am using the following code:

```
private void takePicture() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            "Pic.jpg");
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

}

  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case 0:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
            getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
                bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                        .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);

                imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getHeight()/2, bitmap.getWidth()/2, false));


                Toast.makeText(this, selectedImage.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            }
        }
```

The Picture is definitely showing, but when I change the activity and go back to this one, the picture goes away. How do I save it permanently?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you will have to manually save the image either in SQL Lite or SD Card or wherever you want.

See [this](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/store-imagesfiles-database) for storing image in SQLite

See [this](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/64048.aspx) for storing image in SD Card

Comment: can you look at my new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861820/saving-picture-to-a-file-and-retrieving-it/6861866#6861866 to see if I'm doing this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this as my code is working properly

```
                    public class PhotoActivity extends Activity {

                    /** The Constant PICK_IMAGE. */
                    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 0;

                    /** The Constant PICK_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY. */
                    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY = 1;

                    /** The btn cancel. */
                    private Button btnPhotoCamera,btnPhotoGallery,btnCancel;

                    /** The img view. */
                    private ImageView imgView;

                    /** The u. */
                    private Uri u;

                    /* (non-Javadoc)
                     * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
                     */
                    @Override
                    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_options);

                        imgView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgDisplayImage);
                        btnPhotoCamera=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPhotoCamera);
                        btnPhotoGallery=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPhotoGallery);
                        btnCancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);

                        btnPhotoCamera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                Intent camera=new Intent();
                                camera.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                                camera.putExtra("crop", "true");

                                File f=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

                                u = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"myFile.jpg"));
                                camera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, u);
                                startActivityForResult(camera, PICK_IMAGE);
                            }
                        });

                        btnPhotoGallery.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                                intent.setType("image/*");
                                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY);
                            }
                        });

                        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                Intent goStartUp=new Intent(PhotoActivity.this, StartUpActivity.class);
                                goStartUp.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                startActivity(goStartUp);
                                finish();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    /* (non-Javadoc)
                     * @see android.app.Activity#onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent)
                     */
                    @Override
                    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (resultCode==RESULT_OK )
                        {
                            if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {

                                InputStream is=null;
                                try {
                                    is = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(u);
                                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                                imgView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                                Log.i("Inside", "PICK_IMAGE");
                            }

                            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY) {
                                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                                Log.d("data",filePathColumn[0]);
                                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                                cursor.moveToFirst();
                                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                                cursor.close();
                                imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                                Log.i("Inside", "PICK_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

XML File:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#f0f0f0" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblSelectOptions"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="@string/two_options"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#ff0000" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnPhotoCamera"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lblSelectOptions"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/camera" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnPhotoGallery"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btnPhotoCamera"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/gallery" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btnPhotoGallery"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
                android:text="@string/cancel" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblDisplayImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btnCancel"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/below_this_text_image_will_be_displayed"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="13dp" />
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lblDisplayImage"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="bottom" >
                <!--
                     <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                -->
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgDisplayImage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/lblDisplayImage"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/area_where_image_is_to_be_displayed" />
                <!-- </ScrollView> -->
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Also Modify the Android Manifest file as per your use with following:

```
<manifest....
  <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="3"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
<application....
..........
</application>
</manifest>
```