# Android: Saving Picture to a File and Retrieving it

Tags: java, android, android-layout, image

After taking a picture with my camera, I want to save it in that layout. I also want to save it to a File and be able to load that picture when I create the activity(so if i switch to a different activity and come back to this one). As of now, i can take the picture and display it, but if i switch activities more than once, the picture gets lost.I have the  following relevant code:

I load my picture OnCreate using `setImage()`:

```
private void setImage(){
    if (loadPicture("hello", bitmap) != null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "not null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        imageView.setImageBitmap(loadPicture("hello", bitmap));
    }
}

private void takePicture(){
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    File photo =
            new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Pic.jpg");
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
            getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);

            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

            try {
                bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                        .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);

                imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getHeight()/2, bitmap.getWidth()/2, false));
                //**Where I save the picture**
                savePicture("hello", bitmap, getApplicationContext());


     }

private void savePicture(String filename, Bitmap b, Context ctx){
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream oos;
        FileOutputStream out;// = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        out = ctx.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, oos);

        oos.close();
        oos.notifyAll();
        out.notifyAll();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private Bitmap loadPicture(String filename, Bitmap b){
    // Drawable myImage = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(filename);
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        try {
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        } catch (StreamCorruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        // myImage = Drawable.createFromStream(ois, filename);
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ois);
        try {
            ois.close();
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return myImage;
    return b;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like your code works, but you are losing your image when the activity comes back. Loading your picture onPostResume() instead of onCreate() may be what you need. It feels like the activity lifecycle is the key to your problem. I have a couple of questions I will throw into comments.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear on details that may be telling: When you say switch activities, do you mean to activities that change the photo?  The code you have has a single file being where a photo goes so I could see it getting clobbered if savePicture() is getting called at times you did not expect.  When you say that the picture gets lost do you mean that it does not display; that it is not in the filesystem; or both?

Comment: After I click an item on a list, this activity shows and I have a button to take a picture. It displays then. If I go back to the list, and then click back on the item , then repeat the same thing again, it just doesn't display the same pic anymore.

Comment: as of now, I am not retrieving the File `photo`. It is saved at this line:`File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
    "Pic.jpg");` Should I use this or is it fine as is now?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't display the same pic anymore".  If you would not mind giving us a more verbose step by step reproduction, I may understand better. I sounds like ActivityA(List) > ActivityB(detail with no photo yet) > ActivityC(take a photo) >ActivityB(with photo now)>ActivityA(click item)>ActivityB(photo still there)>ActivityA(click item)>ActivityB(different photo)

Comment: yes, that is correct. the last step, ActivityB(different photo), that different photo is just the icon, as in the default imageView. And by the way, when i switch from B(detail) back to A(list) after taking the picture(I do this twice, as you have noticed), i do  itusing the back button on the phone. Could this be a problem since I do not have a proper intent to do this?

Comment: Hitting back calls onActivityResult() just like hitting finish, but, your code lacks an example of where selectedImage or imageURI comes from. Is there missing code from that block? Does the block get run when you return the second time? For debugging put a Thread.getCurrentThread().printStackTrace() in a setter for that imageURI field and watch it.

Comment: imageURI is in takePicture()... There is also a statement at the beginning of OnActivityResult().  `  imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
`.....I do not believe there is any other code relevant to the picture/bitmap.

Comment: @mbarnes let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1938/discussion-between-kgrover-and-mbarnes)

Comment: It is now working, but I am getting a Suspended (exception OutOfMemoryError). How do i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

```
out = ctx.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Try switching to:

```
out = ctx.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't seem to change anything. Thank you anyways.